# Rails 3.1 respond_to & render_403 problem

Tags: rendering, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm not sure what it is. I've just upgraded to Rails 3.1 from 3.0.9 and here's what I get in my specs:

```
PeopleController edit action should require owner
Failure/Error: response.should render_template("/public/403.html")
expecting <"/public/403.html"> but rendering with <"search/_search_menu_item">
```

This is all over my specs in various controllers. I also have this code in my AppController:

```
def render_403
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/403.html", :status => 403, :layout => false }
    format.json { render :json => { :error => true, :message => "Error 403, you don't have permissions for this operation." } }
  end
end
```

And this in PeopleController:

```
def edit
  render_403 unless @person.account.id == current_account.id
end
```

I'm certain that `format.html` block gets executed (checked it). However the spec expectation fails. Wonder what is going on here.

(`search/_search_menu_item` is a partial that gets included onto every page, which basically means that the app layout gets rendered here instead.)

**Update:** I've replaced `render_403` in `#edit` with `render(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/403.html", :status => 403, :layout => false)` to see what happens - got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Possibly not a Rails problem. At least the problem appears only when running the specs.

I've been checking if 403 pages are rendered with this:

```
response.should render_template("public/403.html")
```

Doesn't work no more. Replacing it with

```
response.status.should == 403
```

fixed the issue.